# How to use if/else statement?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am very new to mathematics but I would like to know how the if/else statement works.

This is what I want:

```
IF a > b
   100 - (a - b)
ELSE 
   100 - (b - a)
```

This is what I have tried:

[image]

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Though I think it would be more common to include "ifs" in your definition of $r$..as in "$\textit {if}\,a>b$" and so on.

Comment: @lulu that was a very fast answer for a very fast solution. Thank you!

Comment: It is worth pointing out that you can still use `else` implicitly rather than having to explicitly name the remaining cases.  You could have written for instance $r = \begin{cases}100-(a-b)&\text{if }a>b\\100-(b-a)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  While not difficult to see or write the remaining case for this example, it can save a lot of time/frustration for much more complicated examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct. By the way, that is equivalent to  $r = 100 - |a - b|$